# How do I implement Remoting with Spring Annotations?

Tags: spring, service, frameworks, annotations, remoting

I have a basic Spring framework web application set up and I am beginning to switch from an XML-based configuration to using annotations. My server and webclient are on different machine, so I have been using the Spring HttpInvokerServiceExporter to enable remoting between them.

Client:

```
<bean id="accountService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">  
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="${server.url}/AccountService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.equinitixanite.knowledgebase.common.service.AccountService"/>
</bean>
```

Server:

```
<bean name="accountService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
<property name="service" ref="accountService"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="example.AccountService"/>
```

My question is, how do I do the same result with annotations? (By which I mean, how can I avoid having to declare every single service in the XML?)

Answer (score 3):

Client:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {
  @Value("${server.url}") 
  private String serverUrl;

  @Bean
  public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean httpInvokerProxy() {
    HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean httpInvoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    httpInvoker.setServiceUrl(serverUrl + "/AccountService");
    httpInvoker.setServiceInterface(AccountService.class);
    return httpInvoker;
  }
}
```

Server:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ServerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public HttpInvokerServiceExporter accountServiceExporter(AccountService accountService) {
    HttpInvokerServiceExporter httpInvokerServiceExporter =
        new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
    httpInvokerServiceExporter.setService(accountService);
    httpInvokerServiceExporter.setServiceInterface(AccountService.class);
    return httpInvokerServiceExporter;
  }
}
```